# How can I write a function to make plots with ggplot2 that takes tibble column names as string parameters?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a tibble with more than 2 variables. I want to create a function that creates a ggplot scatterplot with the x- and y-axis being a variable from the tibble. The function parameters will take a tibble, and two string parameters corresponding to variable names e.g. plot_data(tbl_name, "var1", "var2").

Currently, I have:

```
plot_data <- function(data_tbl, x_axis, y_axis) {
  ggplot(
    data = data_tbl,
    mapping = aes(x = .data$x_axis, y = .data$y_axis)
  ) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth()
}
```

When I run the function, I get the following error:

Error in `geom_point()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `.data$x_axis`:
! Column `x_axis` not found in `.data`.

I don't know what to do to fix this, could anyone please help?

Comment: Use `.data[[x_axis]]` instead of `.data$x_axis` and your function will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function for calling aes with string variables called `aes_string()`. It works like this:

```
plot_data <- function(data_tbl, x_axis, y_axis) {
  ggplot(
    data = data_tbl,
    mapping = aes_string(x = x_axis, y = y_axis)
  ) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth()
}

plot_data(iris, "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")
```

Comment: Just a note: `aes_string()` was deprecated in ggplot2 3.0.0. ℹ Please use tidy evaluation ideoms with `aes()`